# Can blue painter's tape turn glass blue if left on too long?

Tags: painting

A yokel told me that the blue painter's tape can be permanent.  He heard of someone leaving it on the window pane too long ( like a year ) and it turned the glass blue.   Is there any merit to this yokel?

Answer (score 7):

Glass is inert and impermeable, so no merit to the yokel's claim that it turned the glass blue.

That said, like most tape, it can dry out and leave a residue over time. Which can typically be easily scraped off.

Comment: Yup. If you do notice any blue residue on the window, just get yourself a razor glass scraper and it'll come off pretty easily.

Comment: Also, if the glass isn't really glass, but a clear plastic like Plexiglas or Lexan, OR if the window has some sort of tint on it, those CAN absorb dyes that they are left in contact with, and discolor. Regular untinted glass is exactly as DA01 says.